Issue with Batch Generation in Fine-Tuned LLM
I have successfully fine-tuned a large language model (LLM) for text generation, and it performs as expected when generating output for single inputs. However, when I try to generate outputs for the entire test dataset in batch, the behavior is inconsistent or doesn't work as intended.
def predict(input_text):
    device = "cuda:0"
    
    inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=128).to(device)

# Generate predictions
    outputs = model.generate(
        input_ids=inputs["input_ids"],
        pad_token_id=tokenizer.pad_token_id,
        max_new_tokens=100,
        temperature = 0.9,                     
        top_p = 0.9,  
        repetition_penalty = 1.2               
    )
    prediction = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    procedure = prediction[len(input_text):].strip()  # Removing the input text portion
    return procedure

predictions = test_dataset.map(lambda example: {"Predicted_Procedure": predict(example['input_text'])})

this is the code I am using. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and how did you resolve it?
